# Default destructor behavior on reference c++

Tags: c++, standards, destructor

I've searched on internet but i can't find any resources on the behavior of the default destructor on reference.

Example:

```
struct A{
   int &a;
   A(int&i): a(i){}
}
void f(){
    int* i = new int;
    A* a = new A(*i);
    delete a; // is i been destroyed?
}
```

In both cases, where i can find resources about this? Or can someone please explain me how it behaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References are not objects. They don't have destructors. They have lifetimes. Objects have lifetime too, as any other type in C++.

The difference is that, when the lifetime of an object ends, its destructor is called.
But when the lifetime of any other type ends, their resources are simply freed.

In case of a reference, the resource they hold is the memory address pointing to another value. Not the value itself. So when it gets freed, the value stays the same. The stored memory address is what's getting released, not the value.

When you use new/delete, you are manually stating when a lifetime starts (on new) and when it ends (on delete).

In the case of your example, your lifetimes X and Y, would be the following:

```cpp
struct A{
   int &a;
   A(int&i): a(i){}
}
void f(){
    int* i = new int; // ----------------------------------|X
    A* a = new A(i); // -------------------|Y              |X
    delete a; // is i been destroyed? // --|Y              |X
} //                                                       |X
//                                                         |X...
```

As you can see, the lifetime of X continues forever, as you didn't delete it manually but you created it with new. This means that the value that is hold in `i`, would still be valid after the line where you delete `a`.

PD: You should have written `new A(*i)` instead, otherwise you would get a compiler error.

Comment: thank you so much, so is something like "a pointer always dereferenciated"?

Comment: Yeah, references are kind of like a pointer always dereferenciated, but some operations that are possible with pointers are invalid with references also. Like reassign.

Answer (score 2):

Destructing a reference does nothing - it does NOT destroy the referred to object. This becomes clear when you remember that we pass references to most methods. The methods don't destroy the referred to objects.  Pointers are the same. Destroying a pointer does not destroy the object it points at.

In your case, the `int` pointed at by `i` is leaked.

Comment: but just because it was allocated on the heap? if it was allocated on the stack, would it be destructed by the delete or when f ends?

Comment: Anything on the stack is destroyed when the function returns. Again, references do not affect this and it is not affected by references.

Comment: @MooingDuck Anything on the stack, that has a destructor, gets destroyed when the function returns. Raw pointers for example will linger in memory unless you destroy them explicitly.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Well, ok, you're technically right but we can look at this in two ways. The memory they've taken is released, true, but I'm not sure if this can be called "destroying". C++ doesn't zero that memory and it does not perform any other action to clear anything. Values, pointers and everything else just lingers in memory until it is overwritten by something else.

Comment: @NO_NAME The pointer is absolutely destroyed, just like any other object with automatic storage duration. It is true that there is no requirement on the implementation to zero out the memory that it occupied before its destruction. But the lifetime of an object is a well-defined thing, as set out by the standard. This applies to `int`s, `bool`s, pointers just as much as to objects of class type. It's hard to "observe" this, but it definitely is a thing, and is used internally for various optimisations and for reasoning about what your program "means".

Comment: `int main() { int* ptr = nullptr; { int x = 42; ptr = &x; } std::cout << *ptr; }` <-- bad and wrong because of lifetime; can easily crash or eat your cat, and not just because you're accessing "bad memory"

Comment: People like to think of C++ source code as a sequence of instructions passed to your physical computer for execution, but that's just not true.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would become clearer if you'd fix the code so it does compile. You cannot pass a pointer to a method that wants a reference. You need to dereference the pointer first (which is quite a misleading expression in this context).
So you are effectively passing a normal variable.

What you can do with a function that takes a reference is to pass a variable that was never a pointer in the first place.

If you realize that, it becomes much clearer that it would have no sense for the destructor to destroy the referenced value.
It doesn't have any guarantee that it was created dynamically and that it needs to be destroyed.
(Destructors don't even `delete` automatically members that are pointers. You need to do this explicitly.)

Answer (score 1):

To answer short, it is not destroyed, and you get a memory leak.

Now the question is what behaviour you actualy need. There may be different strategies of objects ownership management. The best practice is to use smart pointers instead of the raw pointers, at least for te objects where the ownership is important. For example, you may employ a shared_ptr:

```
struct A{
   std::shared_ptr<int> a;
   A(std::shared_ptr<int> i): a(i){}
}
void f(){
    std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int);
    std::shared_ptr<A> a(new A(i));
}
```

This example opens other questions: should the value pointed by `i` be used somewhere else? Should it survive the object `a`?

If not used anywhere else, you may (and should) use `unique_ptr` instead. Different strategies in life span management may employ other patterns.